# Not able to create proper shape

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

I am trying to create a shape like [image]
But right now what it look like is [image]

Here is my code

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
         <solid android:color="@color/somecolor" />

<corners
    android:radius="10dip"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
         <padding
            android:top="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
```

Any help?

Comment: Change `android:top` to `android:left` and `android:bottom` to `android:right`

Comment: Yeah it works.Thanks a lot.Silly Mistake :P .Can you please write this as answer so I can accept.@abforce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `android:top` to `android:left` and `android:bottom` to `android:right`.

Also you could use negative values for these attributes, so you can finely tune what you would want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

custom_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ff207d94" />
    <padding android:left="2dp"
        android:top="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/somecolor" />
</shape>
```

**Your View**

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/myView"
    android:layout_width="60dp" // width and height will decide the shape
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_layout"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is exactly the problem there (size/hight...).
Have you tried to add some ohter tags to your shape?
I use something like:

```
<shape>
  <gradient
      android:startColor="#525251"
      android:endColor="#838181"
      android:angle="270" />
  <stroke
      android:width="1dp"
      android:color="#525251" />
  <corners
      android:radius="6dp" />
  <padding
      android:left="5dp"
      android:top="5dp"
      android:right="5dp"
      android:bottom="5dp" />
</shape>
```

(width/hight defined in layout XML)